# Can Firebase be used with a Laravel web app

Tags: ios, firebase

I am working on a project that will include a Laravel web application, Android application, and iOS application.  I am new to iOS.  Since a user's data will need to be synchronized across all platforms, I assume the optimal way to do this is with a Relational Database (i.e. MySQL) and a PHP Web Service that interacts with the mobile apps.

Everything I see online says to basically use Firebase for mobile apps.  There is a lot of work to create the PHP Web Services necessary.  I am surprised the dominant recommendation is to use Firebase.  About every iPhone app I have has both web and mobile platforms where data must be synchronized.  I assume they cannot use Firebase and must use PHP Web Services.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct that it is not a foregone conclusion that one would use Firebase. It’s a great solution that fills a particular niche, but developing separate web services is extremely common. (I suspect that that your online research may be biased by the fact that most of these articles are likely geared for mobile developers who might not have the wherewithal to develop, maintain, and support their own web server infrastructure.)

That having been said, I would not have jumped to the conclusion that the “optimal” way would be to write your own backend going against some RDBMS. These NoSQL solutions, like Firebase, are perfectly up to the job in most cases. There are pros and cons on both sides of the NoSQL vs RDBMS discussion (which is probably beyond the scope of this question).

So, do not be unduly biased by these Firebase articles you found online, but consider adding it to your tech stack if:

- there are some compelling Firebase features that you don’t want to reinvent yourself (e.g. the integrated authentication options are nice; the realtime observers for database changes is a killer feature, if you need that; etc.);
- the NoSQL paradigm of Firebase’s “Real-time Database” fits your app’s requirements; and
- you need backend server capabilities, but don’t want to deal with the overhead of developing and maintaining your own backend.

In your case, because you’re already developing a Laravel app, that largely undermines that last rationale, because you’ve obviously already signed up for that.

So, it is just a question of what Firebase features you need and whether these features are compelling enough to justify adding Firebase to your tech stack. But don’t use Firebase because you found a bunch of articles advocating for it. Nor should you dismiss Firebase because you fear it won’t be “optimal”. It depends.

---

All of that having been said, the excellent, seamless, object-to-database mapping that Laravel provides really begs for the SQL database approach. If you tried to use Firebase for the backend, you’d likely lose a lot of the benefits of Laravel.